# The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm running a dart only test in intellij and receiving the following error:

```
The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated, please run "pub get" again.
```

I have tried pub get a number of times.  Any ideas?  I'm on the dev branch of Flutter (anything using Dart 2.7 pretty much fails with the same or a similar error message).

### Edit

I think that if you have a path reference dependency in the pubspec.yaml file it will fail.
Anything like the following fails with the above message if you try to run a dart test in IntelliJ.

```
dependencies:
  test_dependency:
    path: ../test_dependency
```

Comment: I have the same problem with path references but the error is: Error generating build_script snapshot: The pubspec.yaml file has changed since the pubspec.lock file was generated, please run "pub get" again.

Comment: For those who use FVM (Flutter Version Managment tool) and get this error when execute 'flutter pub run build_runner..' -  the correct call will be `fvm flutter pub build_runner..`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not suggesting this is a fix for everyone, but it did resolve my particular situation.

---

Just ran into this error after upgrading flutter from `1.22.6` to `2.0.2` and trying to use `build_runner: ^1.12.2` and `json_serializable: ^4.1.0` to generate json serialization/deserialization classes & methods.

The problem is apparently related to the `pub` package when used with **relative paths for packages** as noted in the following github issues:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2806
- https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/2830

One of the commenters in issue 2806 mentioned running `flutter create .` inside the flutter project folder which rebuilds `.dart_tool/package_config.json`, adding any missing entries, solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

No one solved this problem so far?

I've found a staightforward solution and it works fine for me.

You need to close your IDE (VSCode in my case), make sure that is completely closed using process-monitor.
Then open a terminal window manualy in your project folder and run "flutter pub get"

After that just start your IDE normaly and ewerything will work fine.